# ui-bootstrap popover-trigger expression breaks in version 2.0.0

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

In ui-bootstrap 1.3.3 I had a button with a popover and the following trigger

`popover-trigger="click outsideClick"`

The trigger opened the popover when I clicked the button and closed it when anything else was clicked

In ui-bootstrap 2.0.0 this popover trigger fails on

> Error: $parse:syntax
>   Syntax Error

`Syntax Error: Token 'outsideClick' is an unexpected token at column 7 of the expression [click] starting at [{4}].`

Trying both

`popover-trigger="click"` and 
`popover-trigger="outsideClick"` seems to work but it's not the behavior I require.

Going over their [latest change-log](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/cac6a4534532ca781cfbe59029ee71b25ef8a1b7) I couldn't find any mention of this. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The docs say that `popover-trigger` accepts an expression but turns out it also accepts a string, all I had to do to properly concatenate the triggers was to apostrophe them in the expression

**bad:**

```
popover-trigger="click outsideClick"
```

**good:**

```
popover-trigger="'click outsideClick'"
```

And it all works again as it should

Comment: Even with a single item, I'm finding I need the single quotes within the double quoutes: popover-trigger="'mouseenter'" Not sure when this broke. A shame that the project was bailed on the way it was.

Comment: this is actually how it was supposed to be, you pass a hard coded string from the template to the controller (unlike passing an expression that can be of any type)